# Remove duplicate from foreach

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to remove duplicate form `foreach` but it doesn't work.
I know I can do this with SQL  but I need to use PHP.

My code:

```
<?php foreach($cities as $city):?>
    <a class="btn" href="$city['url'];?>">
        <?= $city['city'];?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Result:

```
> London
> New York
> Paris
> New York
> Berlin
```

I tried with `array_unique` but it doesn't work too.

```
<?php foreach(array_unique($cities) as $city):?>
    <a class="btn" href="$city['url'];?>">
        <?= $city['city'];?>
    </a>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Where I'm wrong?

edit:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [city] => London [url] => London--UK ) 
[1] => Array ( [city] => New York [url] => NewYork--USA ) 
[2] => Array ( [city] => Paris [url] => Paris--France )
[3] => Array ( [city] => New York [url] => NewYork--USA )
[5] => Array ( [city] => Berlin [url] => Berlin--Germany )
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Can we see the array you're using?

Comment: See 'Result:', my code works but display duplicate cities

Comment: Your second method works perfectly for me. Are you sure they are duplicates? No hidden characters or spaces?

Comment: If your `city` and `url` keys are identical for two entries for a city, then `array_unique` should work. If there are non-identical keys, each array item counts as unique. Post your source array?

Comment: I just post my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php 

function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 

    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
} 


?>
```

Use

```
$details = array( 
    0 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mike",    "num"=>"9876543210"), 
    1 => array("id"=>"2", "name"=>"Carissa", "num"=>"08548596258"), 
    2 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mathew",  "num"=>"784581254"), 
); 

$details = unique_multidim_array($details,'id');
```

Source is a User Contributed Notes in http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php